# Using \multicolumn with beamer inside an overlay command

Tags: beamer, tables, overlays

I'd like to have a conditional `\multicolumn` command depending on the slide, so I put it inside an alt or an only command, as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rlll}
  a&b&c&d\\
  A&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}\\ %this is OK
   A&B&C&D\\ %as is this obviously...
  A&\only<-+>{\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}}\only<.->{B&C&D}\\ %but this
  A&\alt<-+>{\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}}{B&C&D}\\% and this do not compile
  A&\multicolumn{3}{l}{\only<-+>{BCD}\only<+->{\begin{tabular}{lll}B&C&D\\\end{tabular}}} %this line works, but, of course, gives the wrong alignment...
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be that LaTeX wants the `\multicolumn` command to appear as the first thing after an & or a newline...but then, as the last line shows, I don't know how to align with the other columns...

Currently I'm solving the problem using `\hspace*` but this is a bit of a ugly hack.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work properly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried sprinkling some magical fairy `\expandafter` dust around to see if the `\only` part could be processed before the ampersand, but it resulted in errors.

This requires only one token of repetition:

```
A\alt<-+>{&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}}{&B&C&D}\
```

I could not get your `\only<-+>`...`\only<.->` construction to work with the `+`s.  It does work with explicit numbers.  But I assume that if the `\alt` construction works you'll take it as preferable.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rlll}
   a&b&c&d\\
   A&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}\\ %this is OK
   A&B&C&D\\ %as is this obviously...
   A\only<1>{&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}}\only<2->{&B&C&D} \\% this works now, but not with -+ etc.
   A\alt<-+>{&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}}{&B&C&D}\\% this works even with -+
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course!! putting the & inside the \alt works perfectly...I'm trying to implement it now in all the use cases and I'll see if still need help. Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

I´m not quite sure what kind of layout you want to create, but i suppose you want some kind of appear/expand thing.

So for me this works:

```
    \begin{frame}

      \begin{tabular}{rlll} % works also in the array/equation construct
      a&b&c&d\\
      A&\multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}\\ %this is OK
       A&B&C&D\\ %as is this obviously...
       \only<2>{A & \multicolumn{3}{l}{BCD}\\} \only<3>{A&B&C&D\\}  % slide 2 appearing slide 3 expanding
      \only<4>{A & \multicolumn{3}{l}{ BCD}\\} \only<5>{A&B&C&D\\} %  and this do not compile
      %A& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\only<-+>{BCD} \only<+->{\noindent\begin{tabular}{lll}B&C&D\\\end{tabular}}} %
% not sure what to do with that line so im dropping it
      \end{tabular}

    \end{frame}
```

So I´m not sure if that fits your expectation but it works. (Its not very efficient code because you have to type the A column every time.)

Comment: You could easily refactor out the duplicate code with some \newcommand calls - and when you're done, you could create a new command that does the work for you (to which you supply the first, second and third columns etc...)